# How can I view recent answers and comments about my questions / answers?

Tags: support, recent-activity

On Stack Overflow, there are currently many ways I can view what I have done — my questions, my votes, my favourites etc. But where is the view that shows me new answers to my questions and comments on my questions and answers?

Comment: Have you really been a member of SO for 9 months and didn't know about the recent activity page? If so that feature needs to be more discoverable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/what-would-be-a-better-icon-for-the-recent-activity-page-or-how-can-that-page-be

Comment: It does need to be more discoverable - I didn't find it even though I was looking. The icon should be just a shortcut and the feature really tab in the user profile. Or at least there should be a textual link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the envelope icon at the top of the page next to your name:

[image: the envelope]

That is your Recent Activity Page.

Comment: That does not look like a free-hand circle, @Shog. SHAME!

Comment: and don't think it doesn't delight me to attach such a thing to a txi post, @lad...

Comment: That's the only reason, I haven't replaced it yet, @Shog.