# “Recent activity” page unnavigable-to

Tags: support, recent-activity, usability, navigation

> **THIS IS A BUGREPORT FOR A USABILITY BUG.**
>
> • **Do not retag as “support”.** This is not a support request.
>
> • **Do not link to the FAQ.** I’ve read it. It doesn’t answer the question “How do I report a usability bug without having it closed and dismissed?”

I just discovered the [Recent Activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/33225) by following the link in the message that alerts me to the fact there are new answers/comments.

However, later I wanted to find that page again and, without the alert message, I couldn’t find it. There is no link to it anywhere, certainly not in my profile (the most obvious place). How am I supposed to navigate to this page?

**EDIT:** I was told that the innocuous little envelope icon in the top bar is a link to this page. *This is undiscoverable* and qualifies as a usability bug that needs fixing. There should be a proper link from the user profile page to the recent-activity page because it is logically part of the user profile.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I view recent answers and comments about my questions / answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/how-can-i-view-recent-answers-and-comments-about-my-questions-answers)

Comment: Please reopen this because it is not a duplicate. It is a bugreport, not a support question.

Comment: "There should be a proper link from the user profile page to the recent-activity page because it is logically part of the user profile" open that as a [feature-request] then

Comment: Without going into semantics about what is a bug exactly, I'm quite surprised to find the recent activity under the icon that is used to indicate an inbox everywhere else on the www. I'd call that a "peculiar design", but heck, what's in a name?

Comment: @joris the function is 99% "show people who responded directly to me" which is exactly the purpose of an inbox.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the envelope next to your name at the top of the screen.

Comment: Does anyone honestly think *that* is discoverable??

Comment: I'm a very new user, and I discovered it as soon as I had comments.  It lights up.  The only way I wouldn't expect a user to notice it would be if they didn't have any responses to their question/answer/comments.  I would hope that is not common for users making an effort.  I suppose it should still be discoverable even without the highlighting, but it *is* an icon, and it does have a pop-up tooltip that mentions "new replies".  How could it be more discoverable?  If it literally said "recent activity" next to it?