# Should a single meta-post be designated as "a central place for reporting" on specific issues?

Tags: discussion, meta

I use mostly beta sites, so the new beta theme has high impact for me.  For the most part it's great, but there's just [one little problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126962/1438) I repeated have.  I dutifully reported the problem in the omnibus [New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126185/1438) and it got some votes, but no answers in the comments.  I don't know what, if anything is being considered.

Now I'd like to give my particular concern a little nudge by spending some reputation to get it bumped.  But I really can't highlight my own report without bringing in all the others.  I'm not sure how I ought to proceed.

I've more or less resigned myself to the idea that we aren't going to get a [real bug tracking system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59307/1438) and MSO does much better than might be expected.  But cramming many related bug reports into a single question seems to cause a breakdown in the system.  Should we discourage askers from trying designate one be-all and end-all question as a clearinghouse for a type of bugs?  Wouldn't the tag system work better for this purpose?

**N.B.:** This isn't really a huge problem in the grand scheme of things, but we really minimize confusion when we can.  I'd like to have a record somewhere that this sort of question is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Answers posted to that question directly ping Jin, the resident theme designer.  How does it get any better than that?

Comment: @Robert: That utterly misses the point.  I am, of course, grateful to have access to Jin and I'm not criticizing him or anyone else.  My question used that particular post because it's the one that currently troubles me.  Please take a step back and consider the general question and not the specific instance.

Comment: Well, I don't agree.  The question you referenced serves a specific purpose very well, and I don't see how discouraging such questions (where they are appropriate) makes things better.  If you really want to highlight your particular issue, leave a comment on your answer to Jin.  Jin will get back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, we use the "report bugs as answers here" format for large, buggy features when they are first rolled out. Devs are supposed to *delete* answers as bugs are fixed, with the entire question getting deleted (or locked, or at very least edited to indicate that this is no longer the place to report all bugs) once all is said and done.

Once the change has been "in the wild" for a bit, posting bug reports as normal, top-level "questions" should be resumed.

Note that with this format - as with *all* bug reports - work is prioritized internally based on the effort required and the larger workload of the developer responsible. Since Jin has been a bit busy with other things lately, this probably just got pushed to the back of the queue.

Comment: Excellent.  Would it be a good, bad or indifferent idea to move my "answer" into a top-level question?   (Obviously, what Jin does with his time is up to y'all.  I'm just trying to get a gauge whether I ought to figure out how to override the relevant CSS or wait for an official solution.)

Comment: @Jon: that's up to you; you don't *have* to.